# Vuejs - automatic event.preventDefault()

Tags: vue.js, preventdefault

right now, I need to add `event.preventDefault()` to all of my click events in my Vue.js buttons:

```
<button class="btn btn-primary" v-on:click="someAction($event)">Action</button></p>

methods: {
 someAction (e) {
   e.preventDefault()
   console.log('in some action')
 },
}
```

Does anyone know of a way have `event.preventDefeault()` be the default setting? Right now it's very annoying to have to include the `event.preventDefault()` in every click event.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/events.html#Event-Modifiers

Comment: thanks - to confirm, in my case I should use `v-on:click.stop="someMethod"` right?

Comment: `.prevent` if `event.preventDefault()` is what you want. `.stop` if `event.stopPropagation()` is what you want.

Answer (score 72):

You can use `prevent` modifier:

```
@click.prevent="YourMethod"
```

You can look [event modifier](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/events.html#Event-Modifiers) for more information.